# Show "InvalidRegistration" when try to send notification in my iOS Ionic App

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I try to send notification to my android and ios IONIC app using FCM. I use

phonegap-plugin-push Plugin : v2.0.0-rc5

I try to send notification from Firebase successfully landed in my Android device but in iOS  in response I get a message "Invalid registration token. Check the token format."

I follow all steps based on phonegap-plugin-push [doc](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#ios-details), and I copy Google-Services.plist created in Firebase in my app folder. in response I get Notification ID also in my iPhone.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Could you show what the tokwn looks like (just remove a portion of it for security)?

Comment: @AL. I get the same error, could you please read my question? I am showing code and step by step explanation with what I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359010